# Technique for smaller Qt setups of C++ apps

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, compilation

I'm a little rusty on my C++ because I'm a PHP dev, and only messed around with C/C++ in college, and C# on one project ten years ago. A C++ developer in my company is using the Qt library. He's saying that we're going to need to put about 15MB of Qt library stuff in a setup.exe, which seems a bit large to me.

Is there a way to change the Visual Studio C++ compiler settings so that it only picks and chooses out of the Qt library that which it actually uses, and its dependencies, and doesn't need to ship this large 15MB Qt library stuff in the setup.exe?

Comment: C# require 250+ MB of .NET framework, AFAIK. Most likely, 15+MB for Qt is the minimal set (QtCore + QtGui + some support module). You can remove dlls your app doesn't use, but the remaining dlls will still take more than 10 megabytes. If you're using mingw, you could switch to microsoft compiler (it produces smaller executables), but that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile Qt statically. It may or may not reduce the size of your final project. You'd need to figure it out on a case-by-case basis. My experience has been that it's not worth the enormous link times when link time code generation (LTCG) is enabled. LTCG is usually worth it as it can not only speed things up, but often it also reduces code size.

As a practical measure, you can use a dynamic Qt library for the debug builds, only use the static Qt for release builds. You'd end up adding two Qt "versions" and two Qt kits to Qt Creator. In Creator parlance, a Qt "version" is merely a Qt build. So if you have two builds (one static, one shared library) of a version of Qt, they'll be two "versions" in spite of sharing a version number.

There's a new benefit available as of Qt 5 when it comes to simple graphical applications. If you don't care about the entire Widget machinery and can paint a simple window yourself, it's quite possible to have an application that uses the `core` and `gui` modules without using the `widgets` module. See [the raster window example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/rasterwindow.html). This saves a couple megabytes worth of a module. Conceptually it's like having a bare-bones MS-DOS application with a good graphics engine :)

In Qt 4 there was no separate `widgets` module, it was bundled within the `gui` module.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Qt application, you only include needed module (QtCore, QtGui, etc, ..)

The more modules you will included, bigger will be the weight of library.

15 MB is not so big compare to other frameworks..

Answer (score 1):

The short answer:

Depends. There was not enough information present in the question to answer it thoroughly.

The long answer:

Qt has developed into a very powerful and flexible suite of tools. Depending on the developers use of Qt, it could easily use several libraries. Currently, in my `/usr/lib64` I see only 17 unique Qt libraries. That means all the functionality provided by Qt is wrapped into only 17 libraries.

For example, a basic executable could use `libQtCore` and `libQtGui` which would make the binary. While a simple dialog box with the addition of a `ping` command could include the previously mentioned two libraries with the addition of `libQtNetwork`. I find it hard to believe that a developer included extraneous libraries *on purpose*.

So, while I'm guessing your developer was a "good guy" and didn't include libraries he didn't need, he may have. Check and see.

And honestly, 15 Mb isn't very large, especially when we have gigabit ethernet and 98347082 GB pen drives.